# Autowiring inside contextInitialized method of Context Listener

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, autowired, bootstrapping

I am trying to autowiring my bean inside contextInitialized() method of my custom Context Listener class, but it is not working.

```
public class CustomContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanClass bean;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent event) {
          super.contextInitialized(event);
          //call to my method.
          bean.mymethod();
}
```

But here it is not getting autowired, i am getting null object for MyBeanClass reference.
How to autowire a class at the time of tomcat startup.
Please provide me alternate places where i can execute some code using autowiring at the time of server startup (here tomcat).

Comment: `ContextLoaderListener` is not itself managed by Spring, it's used to create the application contexts. You can't use autowiring inside it. You need to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to schedule jobs while starting my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the WebApplicationContext method to find the bean and then invoke.

```
WebApplicationContext servletContext =  WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());

bean = (MyBeanClass) servletContext.getBean("myBeanClass");
bean.yourMethod();
```

More systematic to use... :)

Comment: This code works fine, was using this code, but not updated here. It is accepted answer.